# jQuery select the function selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to achieve something inside a function, to actually access the parent selector.

Here is a small snippet of my HTML code:

```
<div class="module-row module-tab pull-right" id="modtab-sql_net">
    <img src="images/icons/icon-orangebox-plus.png" class="modtab-toggle">
</div>

<div id="tab-module-row-1">
</div>

<div class="module-row module-tab pull-right" id="modtab-sql_dss">
    <img src="images/icons/icon-orangebox-plus.png" class="modtab-toggle">
</div>

<div id="tab-module-row-2">
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery script I tried:

```
$('div[id^="modtab-"]').click(function(){
    $(this).next('div[id^="tab-module-row"]').toggle(function(){
        $(this).next('.modtab-toggle').toggle_switch.attr("src").replace("plus", "minus");
// The above line is incorrect. I need to change img attr for the class which is inside the div being clicked
    });
});
```

Now, I want to actually change the image icon from a "plus" to a "minus" (the filenames are kept such).

I need to change `$(this).next('.modtab-toggle')` in the code to something that can work.

Please do NOT suggest to simply access the class using `$('.modtab-toggle')` as I have multiple such `div` tags in the code. It won't work out that way.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why would you use `.next("#tab-module-row")` when logically there can only be one `#tab-module-row`?

Comment: Sorry for making myself unclear. I've edited the question. Please check now.

Comment: `toggle_switch` what is it?

Comment: Well, that's something I found online. It's wrong I know. I added a comment and edited the question. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
    $('div[id^="modtab-"]').click(function(){
        var $this = $(this);// clicked div
        $this.next('.tab-module-row').toggle(function(){
            $this.find('.modtab-toggle').toggle_switch.attr("src").replace("plus", "minus");
        });
    });
```

Note: you should use `class` instead of `id` because it should be unique

`#tab-module-row` ->`.tab-module-row`

**EDITED ANSWER**

```
$('div[id^="modtab-"]').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);// clicked div
    $this.next('div[id^="tab-module-row"]').toggle(function(){
        var img = $this.find('.modtab-toggle'); // your image object
        // your condition to check which image to display will goes here.
    });
});
```

Comment: Will this return the "plus" image when clicked a second time?

Comment: No. It wouldn't I guess. I need to add a condition to check if the element is hidden or not. & then replace it back.

Comment: @rajesh-kakawat I've mentioned in the question, that there are multiple classes for `modtab-toggle` .. I need to toggle only one.

Comment: Yup.. This works. Many thanks! Nice idea to store `$(this)` beforehand. It didn't strike me!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('div[id^="modtab-"]').click(function(){
   $(this).find('.modtab-toggle').attr("src", function(i, attr){
              var o = this.src.indexOf('plus') > -1 ? this.src.replace('plus', 'minus') : this.src.replace('minus', 'plus');
              return o;
          });
});
```

---

#### [See the Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7bJF/)

Comment: Thanks. This seems to work, but it doesn't toggle back from minus to plus. Any idea on what may be going wrong?

Comment: @Tzar change this `this.src.indexOf('plus')` to this `this.src.indexOf('plus') > -1`.

Comment: @Tzar added a fiddle too, you can see this code in action with your markup.

Answer (score 0):

change  `$(this).next('.modtab-toggle')` to  `$(this).find('.modtab-toggle')` to make it work.

See [find() docs here](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: `find()` will not work. I've multiple `div`s with same class images. I need to trigger only on that particular image.